# C++ printf %p specifier behaves differently in Linux and Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, portability

I have a code in C++ that's suppose to work on Linux and Windows.

Part of the code includes using `vsnprintf` in order to get a string using a format string and params.

I notices that whenever the format string contains %p the results are different on Linux and Windows - Windows doesn't prefix the result with 0x while linux does, and also windows uses uppercase for the letters of the address while Linux uses lowercase.

I couldn't find flags to make the two versions be identical.

My preference is to make the Linux version behave like the Windows one (since the Windows code is the original so that's how the program is expected to behave).

And if it's not possible to change the behavior of `vsnprintf` in Linux i would like a method to "fix" the strings that contain %p after `vsnprintf` outputs them (in an efficient way).

Comment: The behavior of `%p` is [implementation defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf#Parameters)

Comment: Probably what you'd want to do is use `uintptr_t`. Something like `std::cout << std::hex << reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(myPointer)`

Comment: Use [`0x%X`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)? not sure if its 100% equivalent.

Comment: @Borgleader: It's not. `0x%X` requires an argument of type `unsigned int`; giving it a pointer has undefined behavior. It might happen to work if `unsigned int` and pointers are the same size (which they very commonly are not); that's always a possible result of undefined behavior.

Comment: Your question is tagged both C and C++. They're two different languages. Which one are you using? (On rare occasions, you might want to write code that works correctly in both languages; if so, please state that in the question.)

Comment: @KeithThompson What if you were to choose between `%lX` and `%llX` based on pointer size? Would that be correct?

Comment: @Borgleader http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer#Format_macro_constants

Comment: @KeithThompson i have updated the question. It's in C++

Comment: @Justin There is no specification how a pointer is converted to `uintptr_t`. Only the conversion to/from those is guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Borgleader:  The `%x` format will not work for pointers of the for *segment:offset*, such as with some of the Intel platforms.  The `%x` format assumes a linear addressing space.

Comment: @Borgleader: No. `%lX` requires an argument of type `unsigned long`, and `%llX` requires an argument of type `unsigned long long`. Passing a pointer is still undefined behavior. It's likely to work, but for example a system might pass pointers and integers in different registers.

Answer (score 1):

The string `%p` prints is [implementation defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf#Parameters). That's why the behaviour is different on Linux and Windows. If you wanted consistent behaviour, you'd have to implement your own version.

Using [`uintptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer#Types), we can have an integer that can hold a pointer. So we can [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Explanation) the pointer into it. Note that, although the conversion will succeed, it's not specified what the value will hold.

Then, we can print the integer as hex, either using [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) or the appropriate [format macro constant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer#Format_macro_constants):

```
auto* myPointer = ...;
std::cout << std::hex << reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(myPointer) << '\n';
std::printf("%" PRIxPTR "\n", reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(myPointer));
```

<sup>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9d67d89142cbe0d)</sup>

The exact formatting would be up to you.

Comment: I'll want to try this solution but i need to be able to programatically at runntime detect every occurrence of `%p` in the format string and replace it with `PRIXPTR`. How can i do that? (detecting is easy but how do i replace the `p` which is a string, with a macro?

Comment: @darkThoughts Note that the format macro constants are `#define`s for a string literal. For example, on coliru, `PRIxPTR` is the same as `"lx"` (of course the actual value will be different on different platforms). So you could find occurrences of `"%p"` and replace them with `"%" PRIxPTR` (which, on coliru, is equivalent to `"%lx"`)

Comment: but since the define is platform dependent i can't just statically replace the occurrences of `"%p"` with `"%X"` or `"%llX"` - i have to replace them with the define. How can i do this?

Comment: @darkThoughts `"some string with %p in the middle"` -> `"some string with %" PRIXPTR " in the middle"`

Comment: How do i do this replacement - do i need to split the original string around `p`?

Comment: @darkThoughts It's not clear what you are asking. If you are looking to do a search-and-replace on your code base, it will take time, but you can search for occurrences of `%p`, ensure it is the case you want, and replace it with `%" PRIXPTR "`. If you are taking the format string as input, you can do something similar (but note that if you are taking the format string as input, [that is a vulnerability](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/43574))

Comment: I am taking it as an input from a remote session. So how would i replace it in that case? I sounds like i have to in runtime split the string: `"before %p after"` around `p` to those parts - `"before %"` and `" after"` and then send to `vsnprintf ` the following as format string: `"before %" PRIxPTR " after"`. correct?

Comment: @darkThoughts Basically

Comment: By the way - i don't see a need for `reinterpret_cast` -= it works the same when i pass `&param` instead of `auto* addr=&param` and then sending `reinterpret_cast(addr)`

Comment: @darkThoughts You can do `reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(&param)`, but if you just passed `&param`, I believe that would be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As [Justin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45199655/827263) suggests, you can convert the pointer to `uintptr_t` and format it as you like. This is likely to be 99% portable -- and since you're probably concerned with just Linux and Windows, that's probably good enough. (It can fail on a system where no integer type is big enough to hold a pointer value without loss of information. Such a system won't define `uintptr_t`. You're unlikely to encounter such a system.)

Another approach is to format the pointer as a string using a `%p` format, and then manipulate the resulting string to get the consistent results you want. It probably makes sense to create a function that takes a `void*` argument and returns a `std::string`.

Here's my attempt (I make no claim that this is good C++ code). It deletes a leading `0x` or `0X` if it exists, and it maps all remaining characters to upper case.

Tweak the `for` loop if you don't have a C++11 compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cctype>

std::string hex(void* ptr) {
    const int big_enough = 100;
    char s[big_enough];
    std::snprintf(s, sizeof s, "%p", ptr);
    std::string result = s;
    std::string prefix = result.substr(0, 2);
    if (prefix == "0x" || prefix == "0X") {
        result = result.substr(2);
    }
    for (auto &&c : result) {
        c = std::toupper((unsigned char)c);
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    int *ptr = &n;
    std::printf("Using %%p:  %p\n", (void*)ptr);
    std::cout << "Using hex(): " << hex((void*)ptr) << "\n";
}
```

The output on my Linux system is:

```
Using %p:  0x7ffd6e8ca884
Using hex(): 7FFD6E8CA884
```